# Sinon to unit test 'catch' statement

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, chai

I've got a simple function such as;

```
module.exports = {
  fetchUser:function(myUserId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.getUser(myUserId)
        .then(user => {
          // do logic // then return user

          return user;
        })
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(err => {
          // whoops there has been an error

          let error = { error: 'My Error' };

          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }
};
```

I want to unit test both the `resolve` and `reject` result.

A simple `chai` test would be;

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var user = require('./user');

describe('User module', function() {
  it('test fetchUser', function() {
    let _user = user.fetchUser('abc123');

    return _user
      .then(user => {
        expect(data).to.be.an('object');
      });
  });
```

Using `sinon` or another library, how can I for the `fetchUser` function to throw that `reject` error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With **Mocha**, **Chai** and **Sinon** it can be implemented with stubbed method `getUser`.

```
const User = require("./fetchUserModule");

describe('User module', () => {
    beforeEach(() => User.getUser = sinon.stub());

    afterEach(() => User.getUser.reset());

    it('returns user if `getUser` returns data', () => {
        const user = {name: 'John'};
        User.getUser.withArgs("abc123").returns(Promise.resolve(user));

        return User.fetchUser("abc123").then(result => {
            expect(result).to.equal(user)
        }).catch(error => {
            expect(error).to.be.undefined;
        })
    });

    it('throws error if `getUser` is rejected', () => {
        User.getUser.withArgs("abc123").returns(Promise.reject());

        return User.fetchUser("abc123").then(result => {
            expect(result).to.be.undefined;
        }).catch(err => {
            expect(err).to.eql({error: 'My Error'})
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. If I setup the test this way it doesn't actually ever enter my catch codeblock does it? The stub just fakes the response to match the error thrown from my catch.

Comment: Yes, it enters to `catch` statement as error is equal to `{error: 'My Error'}`. What you need more to proof that it works?

Comment: Thanks, I was just checking, I don't fully understand stubs yet. I'll test it out.

Comment: I tested it before post answer - it works as expected …

Answer (score 2):

Start with anything in your "logic" that can throw an error.

If not you would need to stub `this.getUser` to reject or throw an error instead of returning data. [sinon-as-promised](https://github.com/bendrucker/sinon-as-promised) patches `sinon.stub` to include the [`.resolves`](https://github.com/bendrucker/sinon-as-promised#stubresolvesvalue---stub) and [`.rejects`](https://github.com/bendrucker/sinon-as-promised#stubrejectserr---stub) promise helpers.

```
const sinon  = require('sinon')
require('sinon-as-promised')
```

Setup the stub for the failure tests.

```
before(function(){
  sinon.stub(user, 'getUser').rejects(new Error('whatever'))
})

after(function(){
  user.getUser.restore()
})
```

Then either catch the `.fetchUser` error or use [chai-as-promised](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) for some sugar.

```
it('test fetchUser', function() {
  return user.fetchUser('abc123')
    .then(()=> expect.fail('fetchUser should be rejected'))
    .catch(err => {
      expect(err.message).to.eql('whatever')
    })
})

it('test fetchUser', function() {
  return expect(user.fetchUser('abc123')).to.be.rejectedWith(Error)
})
```

or `async` if you live in the new world

```
it('test fetchUser', async function() {
  try { 
    await user.fetchUser('abc123')
    expect.fail('fetchUser should be rejected'))
  } catch(err) {
    expect(err.message).to.eql('whatever')
  }
})
```

As a side note, you don't need to wrap something that already returns a promise in `new Promise` and be careful about losing error information when chaining multiple `.catch` handlers.

```
fetchUser: function (myUserId) {
  return this.getUser(myUserId)
    .then(user => {
      //logic
      return user
    })
    .catch(err => {
      let error = new Error('My Error')
      error.original = err
      reject(error)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I didn't realise that last point, I will update my codebase.